# How do we modify an object passed to a function in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, data-structures, tree, binary-tree

I created a small function `funct` which should assign `None` to node if a value of -1 is passed else assign the value to the value attribute of the node object. I created a simple binary tree [root, left, right] and finally print the nodes.

```
class TreeNode:
    def __init__(self, val=0, left=None, right=None):
        self.val = val
        self.left = left
        self.right = right

def funct(node, val):
    if val == -1:
        ### modify code here 
        node = None
    else:
        node.val = val

root = TreeNode()
root.val = 'root'
root.left = TreeNode()
root.right = TreeNode()

funct(root.left, 'left')
funct(root.left, -1)

print(root, root.val)
print(root.left, root.left.val)
print(root.right, root.right.val)
```

When I print the nodes I see the following output.

[image: output]

The right node is in memory and is not `None`.

How do I assign `None` to the orignal object by modifying the code inside the `if` in `funct` to get the following output instead.

esentially simulating the following code and getting the output :

```
root = TreeNode()
root.val = 'root'
root.left = TreeNode('left')
root.right = None
```

[image: output2]

Note : I can change my algo. to create a new node only when val != -1. However I want to understand if there is a way to modify a passed object it in pyhton.

Edits : removed the word "delete". Added some clarification.

Comment: You cannot delete objects in Python. You can remove / replace references to those objects, though

Comment: "I know I can change my algo. to create a new node only when val != -1. However I want to understand if there is a way to modify a passed object without rebinding it in pyhton." huh? You can mutate an object trivially. One thing *that absolutely does not modify an object*, though, is rebinding. So I think you have a fundamental misunderstanding

Comment: "I created a small function funct which should assign None to node (delete the node" *NO*. Assigning `None` to a variable simply assigns `None` to a variable, it doesn't delete anything. This is *crucial* to understand. Read the following: https://nedbatchelder.com/text/names.html

Comment: So TL:DR Python exposes **no way** to delete an object, Python is a fully memory-managed language.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga Thanks for th clarificaiton. I apologise for the confusion I edited my question to add clarity. What I want to understand is can I change the object pointed to by root.right and make it point to None instead. If that makes sense ?

Comment: Furthermore, what you are asking about is **nothing to do with** "deleting" objects. What you are actually asking about is how to replace the caller's variable, so that `root` becomes `None` after the function is called. You **cannot do that, either** from within the function, as also explained in the link above. You can only *modify* the object that was passed in. Your function *does not receive* names. It receives *values*.

Comment: "can I change the object pointed to by root.right and make it point to None instead." Yes, but you have to pass the root itself (so that you can assign to its *attribute*), not the `root.right` value. It would work the same way as the assignment to `root.val` currently works within that function. This means that you will need some way, when calling the function, to know whether it is the left child or the right child that should be modified.

Comment: See also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/986006/how-do-i-pass-a-variable-by-reference

Comment: @RishabhBhatt you can *if you have a reference to `root` by doing `root.right = whatever`*.

Answer (score 2):

> I created a small function funct which should assign None to node if a value of -1 is passed else assign the value to the value attribute of the node object.

`funct` cannot replace the node that was passed to it (i.e.: make one of the caller's variables refer to a new node instead of this one), because it receives **the node**, and *not* any variable name for that node.

It can *modify* the node that was passed to it. In particular, it can replace the child values, by reassigning to `node.right` and `node.left`. This means "the `.right` and `.left` of the `TreeNode` instance that was passed to me". `node` is a name that `funct` uses for that passed-in instance, that has *nothing to do with* the calling code *in any way*.

To "remove" a subtree, then, we need to pass the *parent of* the tree that will be removed, and also indicate which side will be removed. That might look like:

```
def remove_child(parent, which):
    if which == 'left':
        parent.left = None
    elif which == 'right':
        parent.right = None
    else:
        raise ValueError("invalid child name")
```

The root of the tree has no parent, so removing the entire tree must be treated as a special case.

Comment: What if I do '''del node''' for the passed child node inside '''funct'''. What happens to the orignal object root.left / root.right.

Comment: `del` **does not in any way** cause objects to be destroyed, deleted, or in any way modified. It operates on **the name** (or dict key, or list element), **not** the value. `del node` just means "okay, `node` is no longer a name you can use, until you assign to it again". The node that it referred to is still there.

Comment: If in the above code I wrote `del parent.left` instead of `parent.left = None`, then that node would no longer have a `left` attribute, and trying to get its `left` would raise an `AttributeError`. *Either way* would **allow** the subtree to be garbage-collected, **only if** there are **no** other references to it. That's what garbage collection is, after all. It cleans up things that can no longer be referred to, and only those things.

Comment: @RishabhBhatt `del node` deletes the *local* variable from the local namespace. It *does nothing to any objects directly* (of course, it removes a reference to an object, and if an object is no longer referenced by anything, then it is unreachable and free to be garbage collected)

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this is what you need, but I think its doing the behavior you want:

```
class TreeNode:
    def __init__(self, val=0, left=None, right=None):
        self.val = val
        self.left = left
        self.right = right

    def funct(self, child: str, val):
        if val == -1:
        ### modify code here 
            setattr(self,child, None)
    
        else:
            setattr(self,child,TreeNode(val))


root = TreeNode()
root.val = 'root'
root.left = TreeNode()
root.right = TreeNode()

root.funct(child='left', val='left')
root.funct(child='right', val='right')

print(root, root.val)
print(root.left, root.left.val)
print(root.right, root.right.val)
print(None)

root.funct(child='left', val= -1)
print("\n")
print(root, root.val)
# print(root.left, root.left.val) - you cannot print root.left.val because None has no attribute
print(root.left)
print(root.right, root.right.val)
```